# Interpret Spanish Accents Oracle

Tags: oracle, internationalization, globalization

I cannot find functions to help me make an insert to interpret Spanish accents and characters like `ñ`.
Can you lead me? Thanks

For example:

```
INSERT INTO PRUEBA.PRUEBA_EDAD(COD,DABREV,DCORTA,DLARGA,EDAD_MESES,EDAD_ANYOS,FECHA_ACT)
VALUES (60,'60','ENTRE 2 Y 8 AÑOS','ENTRE 2 Y 8 AÑOS',60,5,0,sysdate);
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What is your database character set?

Comment: The [Globalization Support Guide PDF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729.pdf) is a 424 page document so you'll have to be more specific—not to mention that your problems (whatever they are) might be entirely on the client app side (whatever it is).

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain exactly what the problem is?  Are you getting replacement characters (either the ? or upside down ? most likely) when you query the data?  Or something else?

- What are the data types of the various columns (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, etc.)?
- What is the client `NLS_LANG` setting
- What is the database server's database and national character set?

If you're not sure, you can run

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

- What language/ framework/ API are you using to issue the `INSERT` statement?
- What do you get if you `DUMP` the data that is stored in the database

Something like

```
SELECT dump( DCORTA ) 
  FROM PRUEBA_EDAD
 WHERE cod = 60
```

Comment: my problem is that in the table insert strange characters

Comment: COD varchar2,DABREV varchar2,DCORTA varchar2,DLARGA varchar2,EDAD_MESES integer,EDAD_ANYOS integer

Comment: @Jorgechu - OK.  What about the other questions?

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE SPANISH
NLS_TERRITORY SPAIN

Comment: oracle 11g database INSERT language SQL Oracle SQL DEVELOPER AND SQL COMMAND LINE

Comment: @Jorgechu - Are the `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` coming from `v$nls_parameters`?  If so, those are server-side settings, not the client `NLS_LANG` that I asked for.  You will need to post the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` from `v$nls_parameters` as well.  And the results from the `DUMP` function.

Comment: I have execute the next sql sentence : SELECT * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET');  The result is : NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET UTF8

Comment: The result DUMP DCORTA is : Typ=1 Len=20: 69,78,84,82,69,32,49,53,32,89,32,52,53,32,65,239,191,189,79,83

Comment: ENTRE 15 Y 45 A�OS  this is de content

Comment: I have change character set to ISO 8859-1 ? who?